# selecting by date - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I did a complex query from several tables, that return me a list of entities by their id.
the query build like:
"with t as ( --the complex query --) select * from t"

like (it doesn't really matter) :

> 12001
>   12004
>   15003

I also have table that contain 3 columns:

1. sequence (used me also as identity in further)
2. entity (from above)
3. value_date (format: dd/mm/yyyy)

the value date it's not the same for all entity.

For example, the table look like that:

```
seq           entity        value_date 
----------    ----------    ----------  
1580          12001         30/06/2016 
1579          12004         31/05/2016 
1578          15003         30/06/2016 
1577          12001         31/05/2016 
1576          12004         30/06/2016
1575          15003         31/05/2016 
1574          12004         30/04/2016 
1573          67677         30/04/2016
```

I need to run for each entity (from the query, because the table hold also irrelevant entities for me), and select the sequence with the max value_date for the entities.

The result needs to be, list with 3 columns: seq, entity, value_date (the max per entity)

How can I do it?

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: thank for editing, Sujeet Sinha! :-) it's helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need a select where max(value_date)

for each entity

```
select seq,  entity, value_date 
from my_table 
where (entity, value_date) in  (select entity , max(value_date) 
                               from my_table  
                               group by entity);
```

if useful try also this way

```
select a.seq,  a.entity, a.value_date 
from my_table a
inner join my_table b on a.entity = b.entity 
group by b.entity
having  a.value_date = max(b.value_date)
```

Comment: the first solution it's not work for me, because for each entity there is a different value_date (it's possible. in the example I put same date).
<br />
and I don't understand the second solution... it's for one entity? I need one query for all, and get list with: seq, entity, value_date. I hope it's more clearly now :-)

Comment: the second is for all the entity .....  the query select all the rows that  the entity and the date match  the entity and maxdate .. this should be what you have asked .. otherwise .. explain better .,.... if you prefer you can select only the seq ..

Comment: ok. I will try it. maybe because I never wrote like this it doesn't clear for me from first glance

Comment: it's work perfectly... buy I released new issue that I didn't say in my qes... so I need to edit it. because I have some trouble with it.

Comment: In SO  .. is not fair change the question .. if my question is right you should rate the answer as accepted and then post  a new question ..

Comment: you right... but your solution return me all the value_date per entity... so I cant to rate u :(

Comment: My answer should return only the row with entity and max_date  .. not all  row... try again ..

Comment: I don't know... in my computer the result is with a lot of rows... maybe its because I have several rows for same seq+entity+value_date? I don't understand why, but if someone say that the solution is good, I will rate u.

Comment: the internal: what u right after the word "in" (the nested select). the external: what u right before the word "in" (the main select)

Comment: I have added also another way .. hope useful

Comment: so I rated u and I post an new question. thank u a lot!

Comment: I upvoted  you so now > 15  and you can also rate the answers as useful ..